# Windows Installer Cleanup Utility

Tags: windows-7

I am looking for a trustworthy program that can delete useless *.msi and *.msp files (typically left doing some aborted installation or dirty uninstaller) in the `C:\Windows\Installer` folder. I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

There used to be [Windows Installer CleanUp Utility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer_CleanUp_Utility) but its developer, Microsoft, realized it sometimes deleted useful files as well:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same concerns and issues until I stumbled upon [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html).  It's a pretty complete product with deep cleaning support.

Answer (score 1):

Try [IOBit Uninstaller](http://www.iobit.com/advanceduninstaller.html). It cleans the leftovers after uninstallations. I had used both IOBit Uninstaller and Revo Uninstaller, and I prefer IOBit Uninstaller. Do uninstall using IOBit Uninstaller and perform a powerful scan, this will list the leftovers of the uninstalled app.